# Automatically build resource class based of XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, code-generation

In Android applications, resources are specified in xml documents, which automatically are built into the `R` class, readily accessible within the source code as strongly typed.

Is there any way I could use a similar approach for a regular Java desktop application?

What I'd like to accomplish, is both the removal of strings from the code (as a separation of "layers", more or less) and to make it easy to add support for localization, by simply telling the program to choose the xml file corresponding to the desired language.

<sub>I've googled around a bit, but the things I'm looking for seem to be drowning in results about parsing or outputting xml, rather than tools utilizing xml to generate code.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse's message bundle implementation (used by plugins for example) integrates with the Externalize Strings feature and generates both a static class and a resource properties file for your strings:

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/documents/3.1/message_bundles.html

For this integration to work Eclipse needs to see org.eclipse.osgi.util.NLS on the class path. From memory, the dependencies of the libraries it was available in were a little tricky for the project I used this approach in, so I just got the source and have it as a stand-alone class in my core module (see the comments for more on that).

It provides the type safety you're looking for and the IDE features save a lot of time. I've found no downsides to the approach so far.

Edit: this is actually what ghostbust555 mentioned in the comments, but not clear in that article that this isn't limited to Eclipse plugins and you refer to your resources via static members of a messages class.

I haven't seen any mention of others using this approach with their own applications, but to me it makes complete sense given the IDE integration and type safety.

Comment: This looks extremely promising. I am running Eclipse 3.7.1, and when I click "Externalize strings..." in the menu I still seem to have the old version. How do I get the new version working?

Comment: You need the NLS class on the project classpath. In my case, rather than messing with libraries for the dependency, I got the code, added it to my project (must retain the package!) and replaced the minor logging dependencies with the framework I was using. Class is here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.5/org.eclipse/osgi/3.5.0/org/eclipse/osgi/util/NLS.java

Comment: OK, I got it working =) However, I can't figure out how to use this approach for localization (i.e. specifying different languages for the UI).

Comment: Great! This is another nice thing about the framework: it falls back to properties files through file_language_COUNTRY.propeties to file_language.properties and finally file.properties using Locale.getDefault() to determine the current system locale. You can use system propeties and the setDefault() method to set the locale yourself: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault()

Comment: Oh, and of course if you're wanting to change locales on the fly, you need to call NLS.initializeMessages(BUNDLE_NAME, Messages.class) on your bundle(s) to rebind the strings.

Comment: This seems like a perfect solution. Many thanks! (It seems I can't award you the bounty until tomorrow, though...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean but check out internationalization- http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-automatic-i18n.html

Comment: Seems to be something like what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, the tutorial is entirely made for NetBeans, and I'm using Eclipse...

Comment: Using Eclipse's built-in "Externalize strings" feature does allow me to lift out the strings from my GUI files and put them in resources, but it still doesn't result in generated, type-safe classes. What I'm after is a tool to actually build *code* with my strings in, not *only* lift the strings from resource bundles.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something that parses XML files and generates Java instances of similar "struct-like" objects, like [JAXP](http://java.sun.com/webservices/reference/tutorials/jaxp/html/intro.html#gceza), and [JAXB](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JAXB/article.html)?

Comment: I would prefer something where I didn't have to define the xml scheme and create the parsing code myself - since I only want really simple objects (structs, more or less, albeit with `String` properties) I was hoping there was something already in place.

Answer (score 0):

I came across ResGen which, given resource bundle XML files generates Java files that can be used to access the resources in a type-safe way.

http://eigenbase.sourceforge.net/resgen/

Comment: This looks extremely promising - just the sort of thing I wanted. We are not currently using ant for building, but this might make it worth taking the step...